# Checking for a class dynamically added from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

A bit of a weird situation here. I know this is far from the ideal setup, but this is what I am stuck working with, without much leniency to approach it a different way.

Basically, I have a modal window, which has an email signup form embedded via iframe.

I have a script inside of the iframe that sets a class to the main modal when the submit button is pressed. To set the class on the modal, I am using the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function(e) {
    window.parent.$("#modal-popup").addClass("submitted");
}
```

I have verified that this code works fine. In inspector, whenever I press the submit button, I see the "submitted" class gets added to the modal.

However... outside of the iframe, I have another script running, that checks when the users presses the close button on the modal.

I want it so that if the modal has the class of "submitted", it does one thing - but if it doesn't have that class, it does something else.

So I have the following:

```
$(".close-exit-modal").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($("#modal-popup").hasClass("submitted")) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, every single time I try the script, the "do something else" runs. The modal clearly shows that it has the proper class - and for the life of me, I can't figure out why this script wont recognize it.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Is the missing ) a typo? `window.parent.$("#modal-popup").addClass("submitted");
}` Any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to have the ability to change the parent, that to me signifies that you are on the same domain.  So potentially you could do some different things.

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function(e) {
    window.parent.$("#modal-popup").addClass("submitted");
    //directly call a method in the parent to let it know the class changed
    window.parent.modalPopupWasSubmitted();
});

$(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function(e) {
    window.parent.$("#modal-popup").addClass("submitted");
    //trigger a custom event that your parent page can have an event listener for
    $(window.parent).trigger('modalWasSubmitted');
});
```

Optionally, depending on the browser support you need, you could also potentially use a `postMessage` to let the parent know that something happened.  Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage